# same jvm options, different gc output of tomcat and jetty

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, jvm, jetty

I use the same jvm options to run a webapp in tomcat and jetty, but I got totally different gc outputs.

```
jdk: jdk1.8.0_45
tomcat: tomcat-8.0.22
jetty: jetty-9.2
```

jvm options:

```
-Xmx4G -Xms4G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=400 -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:/opt/logs/gc/timediff-gc-tomcat.log  -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/opt/logs/gc/timediff-tomcat-oom.hprof
```

I use `jstat -gc 8339 20s` to get the gc outputs.

the output of gc under tomcat:

```
S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
0.0   19456.0  0.0   19456.0 1963008.0 454656.0 1163264.0   23188.0   41932.0 41027.3 4812.0 4617.4     12    0.419   0      0.000    0.419
0.0   19456.0  0.0   19456.0 1963008.0 523264.0 1163264.0   23188.0   41932.0 41027.3 4812.0 4617.4     12    0.419   0      0.000    0.419
0.0   19456.0  0.0   19456.0 1963008.0 586752.0 1163264.0   23188.0   41932.0 41027.3 4812.0 4617.4     12    0.419   0      0.000    0.419
0.0   19456.0  0.0   19456.0 1963008.0 651264.0 1163264.0   23188.0   41932.0 41027.3 4812.0 4617.4     12    0.419   0      0.000    0.419
0.0   19456.0  0.0   19456.0 1963008.0 715776.0 1163264.0   23188.0   41932.0 41027.3 4812.0 4617.4     12    0.419   0      0.000    0.419
0.0   19456.0  0.0   19456.0 1963008.0 780288.0 1163264.0   23188.0   41932.0 41027.3 4812.0 4617.4     12    0.419   0      0.000    0.419
0.0   19456.0  0.0   19456.0 1963008.0 843776.0 1163264.0   23188.0   41932.0 41027.3 4812.0 4617.4     12    0.419   0      0.000    0.419
0.0   19456.0  0.0   19456.0 1963008.0 908288.0 1163264.0   23188.0   41932.0 41027.3 4812.0 4617.4     12    0.419   0      0.000    0.419
```

the output of gc under jetty:

```
S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
0.0   8192.0  0.0   8192.0 382976.0 108544.0 3803136.0   47412.0   46208.0 45242.9 5248.0 4927.3      6    0.290   0      0.000    0.290
0.0   8192.0  0.0   8192.0 382976.0 108544.0 3803136.0   47412.0   46208.0 45242.9 5248.0 4927.3      6    0.290   0      0.000    0.290
0.0   8192.0  0.0   8192.0 382976.0 108544.0 3803136.0   47412.0   46208.0 45242.9 5248.0 4927.3      6    0.290   0      0.000    0.290
0.0   8192.0  0.0   8192.0 382976.0 112640.0 3803136.0   47412.0   46208.0 45242.9 5248.0 4927.3      6    0.290   0      0.000    0.290
0.0   8192.0  0.0   8192.0 382976.0 112640.0 3803136.0   47412.0   46208.0 45242.9 5248.0 4927.3      6    0.290   0      0.000    0.290
0.0   8192.0  0.0   8192.0 382976.0 112640.0 3803136.0   47412.0   46208.0 45242.9 5248.0 4927.3      6    0.290   0      0.000    0.290
0.0   8192.0  0.0   8192.0 382976.0 112640.0 3803136.0   47412.0   46208.0 45242.9 5248.0 4927.3      6    0.290   0      0.000    0.290
```

For my understanding, the total `heap` is 4G; the default value of `-XX:NewRatio` is 2, so new capacity is about 2.6G, and the old capacity is about 1.4G; the value of `-XX:SurvivorRatio` is 8, so eden capacity is about 2G, survivor capacity is about 260M; So I cannot understand the above gc logs.

Could anybody helps? Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you also post an output of `jstat -gccapacity ...`?

Comment: @mazaneicha,  

       `NGCMN    NGCMX     NGC     S0C   S1C       EC      OGCMN      OGCMX       OGC         OC       MCMN     MCMX      MC     CCSMN    CCSMX     CCSC    YGC    FGC 
         0.0 4194304.0 2641920.0    0.0 8192.0 2633728.0        0.0  4194304.0  1552384.0  1552384.0      0.0 1093632.0  48640.0      0.0 1048576.0   5376.0      7     0
         0.0 4194304.0 2641920.0    0.0 8192.0 2633728.0        0.0  4194304.0  1552384.0  1552384.0      0.0 1093632.0  48640.0      0.0 1048576.0   5376.0      7     0`

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it `NewRatio` only sets the initial new generation size. The adaptive sizing policy will resize the generations as needed to meet various GC goals.

I think you shouldn't start tuning those things unless any of your higher-level goals (throughput, pause times, footprint) aren't met. Leave it to the GC's heuristics if you can.

Comment: Thanks. From the jstat output of jetty, I think `NewRatio` sets the limit (max value) of new generation.

Comment: Hrrm, possibly. The either the option is outright ignored or interpreted differently when `UseAdaptiveSizePolicy` is enabled, which it is by default.